# Using 10.10.3 beta -- Applescript is totally borked

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite-beta

I upgraded to the `10.10.3` beta from Apple (build `14D87p`) because I wanted to give them feedback on Photos, which I want to be a good app. On the laptop everything seems fine, but on the iMac I'm bummed to say that `Applescript` has become quite borked. Several basic scripts refuse to work, including this one, which returns the active tab of a Chrome window.

tell application "Google Chrome"
    get URL of active tab of first window as text
end tell

(This is my production computer, which was stupid of me I know.)

Mainly I'm posting to a) warn others that `Applescript` is potentially messed up badly in `10.10.3 beta 2`, and b) to ask if anyone knows anything to try, some "Applescript cache" I can reset or anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you have had a look into the error console?

You can also read the Tech Note "Debugging Magic" to enable debugging of Chrome, so you can see what is going on. Unless of course that you are familiar with dTrace.

Chrome isn't a native app at all, so to say that AppleScript is "Borked", because some script is doesn't work, is quite far fetched IMHO.